# Random 3-manifolds in $R^4$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, 3-manifolds

Consider following program:

1. Generate random 3-manifold embedded in $R^4$.
2. Perform its triangulation.
3. Put it to [Regina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regina_(program)) and calculate what manifold it is.

Assuming that we have good algorithm for random submanifolds in point 1. then we can conclude which 3-manifolds of of complexity 5,6,7,8 etc are embeddable in $R^4$. For example from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405250.pdf) paper I can see that there are 175 3-manifolds of complexity 7. Those which were not obtained in this process we can assume are not embeddable in $R^4$ with some probability.

Possible choices for algorithm in point 1 are:

a) zero of four variables polynomial;

b) random embedded 1-surgery;

c) gluing cubes;

d) drilling small hole cubes in big cube;

e) boundary of regular neighborhood of 2-complex in $R^4$ (added 2018-08-23)

The questions are:

**A.** What are achievements in finding good polynomial of four variables hoping to obtain interesting 3-manifold as its zero ?

**B.** What could be the algorithm for finding random loop in $M$ embedded in $R^4$ to perform embedded surgery ?

**C.** Is Regina accepting command line execution with some input in TXT file containing triangulation and producing result (or LOG) in other TXT file ?

Related questions are:

**D.** What could be other ideas for producing random 3-submanifolds of $R^4$ ?

**E.** How could we generate random slice knots and what manifolds we obtain by repeating 1-surgery on slice knots ?

**F.** Is it known which 2-dimensional CW-complexes are embeddable in $R^4$ ? Such CW-complex can be seen as few words in set of generators which are forming bouquet of circles. I am hoping all 3-manifolds embeddable in 4-space are boundaries of regular neighborhoods of some 2-complex.

**EDIT 2018-07-30**

Regarding last question. I have been able to find embedding of 2-complex with one word in 4-space. So I thought to use this as starting point. Assuming that this 2-complex is defined as 2-skeleton in $\mathbb R^4$. Related question is

**F2.**
Is it known algorithm for finding regular neighborhood of 2-skeleton in $R^4$ ?
If I have it then I find its triangulated boundary as 3-manifold I want. The 3-simplex belongs to boundary when it belongs to only one 4-simplex.

**EDIT 2018-08-23**

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32787/word-problem-for-fundamental-group-of-submanifolds-of-the-4-sphere) question I found reference to the paper:

*Dranišnikov, A. N.; Repovš, Dušan*, [**Embedding up to homotopy type in Euclidean space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700012338), Bull. Aust. Math. Soc. 47, No. 1, 145-148 (1993). [ZBL0796.57011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0796.57011).

In this paper there is construction of embedding of any 2-complex in $R^4$ up to homotopy type. It is described as simpler proof of Stallings theorem from 1965. Therefore I am planning to convert that construction to simplicial complex in $R^4$. Next construct its regular neighborhood, its boundary will be 3-manifold which I would like to recognize using Regina or other software.

What is not clear for me is why embedding of 2-complex in $R^4$ listed as open issue number 5.3 on Kirby's open problem list.

Regards,

Comment: What the hell is Regina? :D

Comment: (I didn't downvote, for the record..)

Comment: I added link to wikipedia page for Regina software. It calculates fundamental group, homology groups and determine type of 3-manifold based on its triangulation.

Comment: Have you looked at Budney-Burton https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2346v5? It investigates subcomplexes of $R^4$ via Regina and so seems related to some of what you ask for. As to question F, I think this is not known. There are some comments in Kirby's problem list (https://math.berkeley.edu/~kirby/problems.ps.gz) on the subject (see problem 5.3, attributed to R. Fenn). Also, in problem F it's more correct to refer to a regular neighborhood rather than tubular neighborhood.

Comment: Regarding C, see Regina's python interface https://regina-normal.github.io/docs/python.html . There is a command-line interface regina-python for macOS and linux, but not windows, apparently.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Yes, I looked into "11 tetrahedron census". I corrected "regular neighborhood". Currently I have no access to post script viewer. I will take a look later on into Kirby problem list. Regards. 
Regarding Regina. unfortunately I am using windows currently. I have many other obstacles in my "project", opening unix shell somewhere would be easy one...

Comment: There is a compiled version of Regina for Windows, FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding A: As far as I know, there's only some special cases and no big familiy of interesting examples known.

Regarding C: Yes, Regina has a fairly good Python interface.  We don't have every feature of the C++ library implemented in Python, but quite a bit is.

Regarding D: Perhaps the most sensible way to define a "random submanifold of $R^4$" would be to start with the standard triangulation of $S^4$, and sequentially do barycentric subdivision. A "random" submanifold could be a vertex-normal solution to the normal 3-dimensional submanifold equations. This is something I do with Regina systematically and it's one of the more fruitful ways of generating 3-dimensional submanifolds of $S^4$. Unfortunately, you generate the simplest 3-manifolds the most often, much like with random knot algorithms.  It's unclear to me how to make this more effective, other than throwing enormous computational power at the problem.

Regarding E: I don't think people have any great algorithms for producing random slice knots.  You either have to restrict to fairly specific knot families or live with cripplingly slow algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I accepted it. I am reading Regina Handbook to understand what is "normal vertex hypersurface" in 4-manifold.

Comment: I peform following steps in Regina: - New Topology Data, New 4-Triangulation (4-sphere minimal); created 2 pentachorons. Select barycentric subdivision; 240 pentachorons are present. Next click icon New Normal Hypersurface List. The dialog Working is shown with description "Enumerating vertex hypersurfaces (double description method). The progress reach 2% and does not move. I click "Cancel" after half an hour. I am using Windows version of Regina 5.1

Comment: Right.  Normal 3-manifold enumeration in a 240 pentachoron sphere will be horrifically slow.  To avoid these kinds of issues what I tend to do is more of a random walk on the Pachner graph -- i.e. I do various Pachner moves to complicate the triangulation.  If you keep it under 24 or so pentachora, enumeration should be fine on "normal" home computers.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Now I am more willing to use GAP package "simpcomp" for work with simplicial complexes. My program is now: 1) take 2-complex; 2) calculate regular neighborhood in $R^4$ (in this point not certain whether 2-complex can be embedded there); 3) calculate homology of simplicial complex obtained this way; 4) look around for other 3-manifold recognition methods.

Comment: I noticed "drill edge" function in Regina, so I am now considering Regina. How can I perform 1-surgery on 3-manifold using path in 1-skeleton ? First I drill all edges on this path. But next how should I glue torus ?