# Can every finitely presented group be realized as a fundamental group of a compact four-dimensional smooth submanifold $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, manifolds

Every finitely presented group is realized as a fundamental group of a two-dimensional complex (a simple exercise on Van Kampen's theorem). I was told that a two-dimensional complex can be well embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$ so that its tubular neighborhood (as well as its closure) deformatively retracts onto it (if I'm not confusing anything; what is the name of the theorem that ensures this?). Thus, every finitely presented group is realized as a fundamental group of a compact five-dimensional smooth submanifold $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Is it true that the compact four-dimensional smooth submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^4$ are sufficient for realizing every finitely presented group as a fundamental group?

Comment: If I remember it correctly, Stallings proved that every finite CW complex is homotopy-equivalent to one which embeds in $R^4$. He also proved a similar result in higher dimensions.

Comment: Yes, that's right (but unfortunately it doesn't help answer the question, I think). Could you suggest why a two-dimensional finite complex can be built into R^5 with a tubular neighborhood that retracts deformationally onto it? Is it true that in this case it will be an embedded smooth manifold?

Comment: Every regular nbd deformation retracts. And no need to work in $R^5$.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30238/constructing-4-manifolds-with-fundamental-group-with-a-given-presentation

Comment: @AGenevois Thank you very much, this answers my questions in brackets!

Comment: No, I'm telling this that it's known in $\mathbb{R}^5$ and asking if the same is true in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: Stallings's result is contained in his unpublished (but [available](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.486.2722)) notes. An alternative and shorter proof of the result appears in the paper [Embedding up to homotopy type in Euclidean space](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/embedding-up-to-homotopy-type-in-euclidean-space/3F82F7BCD77CD94F5C17F90A70BD9766) by Dranishnikov and Repovš, which affirms that every fp group is the $\pi_1$ of a 2-dimensional polyhedron embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan answers your question, with the caveat that the CW-complex being discussed has to be 2-dimensional.  A smooth regular neighbourhood of the CW-complex is the 4-manifold you are looking for.  Returning to my 1st sentence, not every 3-dimensional CW-complex embeds in $\mathbb R^4$.