# Which Abelian Group sequences arise as the Homology of Embedded CW Complexes?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

### Background

Let $\mathcal{A} = \lbrace A_0, \ldots, A_M \rbrace$ be an arbitrary sequence of finitely generated Abelian groups. It is well-known that a finite CW complex $X_\mathcal{A}$ may be constructed so that its $m$-th homology group $H_m(X_\mathcal{A})$ equals $A_m$ for all $0 \leq m \leq M$. In particular, one can build wedge sums of [Moore spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(algebraic_topology)).

On the other hand, any CW complex is an Euclidean neighborhood retract (see Hatcher corollary A.10) and hence embeds into some Euclidean space. By a *geometric complex* of dimension $n$ I mean a CW complex whose minimal Euclidean embedding dimension is $n$.

### Question

What $\mathcal{A}$'s arise as homology sequences for $n$-dimensional geometric complexes as a function of $n$?

### Notes and Considerations

Some obstructions to having a CW complex embed in Euclidean space are outlined in the answers to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19618/when-does-a-cw-complex-of-dimension-2-embedd-in-r4) older question and may be helpful although I have not been able to use them efficiently. What one can say immediately about the sequences $\mathcal{A}$ arising from an $n$-dimensional geometric complex is that all but the first $n-1$ groups must be trivial by dimension considerations, and that the $(n-1)$-st group must be torsion-free. Alexander duality imposes constraints as well, but it is unlikely that this list of conditions characterizes the $\mathcal{A}$'s that are possible homology groups of geometric complexes. Is there a complete answer available somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simpler than that other question, because it's only the homology and not the homotopy type that is being prescribed.

A Moore space with $H_1$ finite cyclic can be embedded in $4$-space, so by suspending this a Moore space with $H_m$ finite cyclic can be embedded in $n$-space if $1\le m\le n-3$. And of course an $m$-sphere can be embedded as long as $0\le m\le n-1$. Wedging together such Moore spaces and spheres you can achieve any sequence of finitely generated homology groups such that

$A_m=0$ for $m\ge n$

$A_{n-1}$ and $A_{n-2}$ are torsionfree

$A_0$ is torsionfree and nontrivial.

Of course you can also achieve $A_m=0$ for all $m$ by taking $X$ to be empty. The other trivial case not satisfying the conditions above is a point embedded in $0$-space.

Conversely, the homology of any finite complex $X$ in $n$-space (other than those two trivial cases) must satisfy the conditions above.

The fact that $A_{n-2}$ is torsionfree follows from duality. Without loss of generality $X$ is a compact $n$-manifold-with-boundary in $n$-space. The map $H_1(X)\to H_1(X,\partial X)=H^{n-1}(X)$ is zero because it factors through the map $H_1(B)\to H^{n-1}(B,\partial B)$ for a closed ball $B$ containing $X$. This makes $H_1(X,\partial X)$ inject into $H_0(X)$, which is impossible if there is torsion in $H_{n-2}(X)$ and therefore in $H^{n-1}(X)=H_1(X,\partial X)$.

Comment: Tom, thank you very much for this answer. But how does it follow that $X$ is a compact $n$-manifold with boundary in $n$-space? For example, the minimal CW decomposition of the $2$-sphere embeds in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but surely not as a compact $3$-manifold, so I must have misunderstood something in the "without loss of generality" part.

Comment: @Vel Nias: I think Tom is using the fact that a finite complex embedded in a manifold has a regular neighbourhood which deformation retracts to the complex. This is, by definition, a manifold with boundary, and it is compact if $X$ is finite.

Comment: I don't need the complex to be a deformation retract of a compact manifold neighborhood, just a retract. (A retract of a torsionfree group is torsionfree.) To get such a neighborhood, use that a finite complex is an ENR, and that every neighborhood of a bounded set in $n$-space contains a compact manifold neighborhood